# Any advantage to checkpoint model very frequently

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently learning Tensorflow, and found checkpointing interesting.

I'm wondering if you think there is any advantage if we can checkpoint the model literally every step? Would that help debugging and finding the best model?

Comment: Any possible advantage would be completely overshadowed by the massive memory requirements as well as the slowdown (checkpointing takes a while).

Comment: @xdurch0 Would this be helpful for debugging the model from these checkpoints? I was thinking with these many checkpoints, it might be easier to understand what's going on when we are trying to develop some model.

Answer (score 2):

You want to save the best checkpoint in general. As a model evolves quite slowly during training every X training steps you can validate your model and then save it if it is better than the previous one.